# synchronizing global variables in a servlet

Tags: java, servlets, synchronization

I have a couple of global variables in a servlet.   Individual servlet sessions read from and wrote to these variables.   They are used to coordinate values posted to a database so it is important that the sessions remain in synch.   My question is can I use synchronize key words with servlets to keep different servlet sessions from colliding with each other at these global variables?

Thank you,

Comment: it would be better if you describe what you want to achieve. i kind of sensing you are mixing individual requests with sessions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend not doing stuff like this in the servlet class itself.  Have your servlet's doGet() etc. call into another object to do the real work.  If this delegated class is a singleton then you have full control over initialization, state etc.

If you rely on how the app server loads the servlet class itself things can get brittle.  Best to just let the server classload/share the servlet whenever it feels like and not depend on specific behavior.

Comment: Alternatives may be session variables (modified inside a synchronized method), or memcached (again changes applied inside a synchronized method).